# Finding all positive integers $m,n$ such that $\frac{n^3+1}{mn-1}$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Determine all ordered pairs $(m,n)$ of positive integers such that $\dfrac{n^3+1}{mn-1}$ is an integer.

My work:
$$\frac{n^3(m^3+1)}{mn-1}=\frac{(mn)^3-1}{mn-1}+\frac{n^3+1}{mn-1}.$$
Since, $\frac{n^3+1}{mn-1}$ is an integer, $mn-1 \mid n^3(m^3+1)$ but $\gcd(mn-1,n^3)=1$. So $mn-1 \mid m^3+1$. Now, if $m=n$, we get $n=2$, so one solution is $(2,2)$. If $m>n$, and $n=1$, then $$\dfrac{n^3+1}{mn-1}=\dfrac{2}{m-1}.$$ We get $m=2,3$. So solutions are $(2,1),(3,1)$.

Now, I cannot do anything beyond this to complete the solution. Please help.

Comment: http://books.google.de/books?id=RaPtb9KBfBQC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=that+n3%2B1mn%E2%88%921+is+an+integer&source=bl&ots=btOLlXjWIA&sig=lcR4hsu8n3QmSrvkYDulo0L16aE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vqIEU8DDN6fNygP-soHQCg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: This is IMO 1994 #4. See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1994_IMO_Problems/Problem_4) for a solution.