# find all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\large\frac{n^3+1}{mn-1}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

### find all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\large\frac{n^3+1}{mn-1}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

---

my attempt :

I) if $(m=n)$ :$$n^2-1|n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)\Longrightarrow n-1|n+1\Longrightarrow n-1|1$$
so the only answer in this case is $(m=n=2)$

II) if $(m\not=n)$ :

suppose that $(m>n\ge2)$ and $\big(\large\frac{n^3+1}{mn-1}$$=T\big)$ so $\big(n^3+1=(mn-1)T\big)$ now :$$n^3+1\equiv(mn-1)T\pmod n\Longrightarrow T\equiv-1\pmod n \Longrightarrow T=nq-1$$$$nq-1=\frac{n^3+1}{mn-1}$$

Comment: See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2023p6413)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682032/finding-all-positive-integers-m-n-such-that-fracn31mn-1-is-an-integer?noredirect=1).

Comment: NCB and Dietrich linked to the same post from 2014. It's interesting how the same variables were used, and which helped the search engine. If it was instead $$\frac{b^3+1}{ab-1}$$ I guess the old post would have been harder to find.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281075/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730149/242) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2023p6413) for more on this old problem ([1994 IMO Problem 4](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1994_IMO_Problems/Problem_4)), and see many other posts on "Vieta jumping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l,m,n\in\Bbb{N}$ be such that $\frac{n^3+1}{mn-1}=l$. Then
$$l(mn-1)=n^3+1,$$
and in particular $l\equiv-1\pmod{n}$, say $l=kn-1$ for some positive integer $k$. Then
$$n^3+1=l(mn-1)=(kn-1)(mn-1)=kmn^2-(k+m)n+1,$$
from which it follows that the integer $n$ is a root of the quadratic
$$X^2-kmX+(k+m)=0.$$
This means the discriminant is a perfect square, i.e.
$$d^2=(-km)^2-4(k+m)=k^2m^2-4k-4m.$$
We see that $d\equiv km\pmod{2}$, and because $k$ and $m$ are positive integers we see that $d<km$ and so
$$k^2m^2-4k-4m=d^2\leq(km-2)^2=k^2m^2-4km+4,$$
from which it follows that
$$4km-4k-4m-4\leq0,$$
or equivalently
$$(k-1)(m-1)\leq2.$$
We see that either $k=1$ or $m=1$ or else $k=m=2$ or $\{k,m\}=\{2,3\}$. We check these few cases:

If $m=1$ then
$$l=\frac{n^3+1}{n-1}=n^2+n+1+\frac{2}{n-1},$$
which shows that $n-1$ must divide $2$, yielding the pairs $(m,n)=(1,2)$ and $(m,n)=(1,3)$.

Similarly, if $k=1$ then $l=n-1$ and so
$$mn-1=\frac{n^3+1}{n-1}=n^2+n+1+\frac{2}{n-1},$$
which shows that again $n-1$ must divides $2$, yielding the pairs $(m,n)=(5,2)$ and $(m,n)=(5,3)$.

If $k=m=2$ then $n$ is a root of
$$X^2-4X+4=0,$$
and so $n=2$, yielding the pair $(m,n)=(2,2)$.

If $\{k,m\}=\{2,3\}$ then $n$ is a root of
$$X^2-6X+5=0,$$
and so $n=1$ or $n=5$, yielding the pairs $(m,n)=(2,1)$ and $(m,n)=(3,1)$, and $(m,n)=(2,5)$ and $(m,n)=(3,5)$.

Answer (score 0):

I had this written up, so I might as well post it.

This is equivalent to finding for which $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$, $m=(n^3+k+1)/kn \in \mathbb{N}$.

First of all, $m>0$. From the above expression, $k+1\mod n=0 \implies k+1=an, a>0$. We can decrease the exponent of $n$ in the denominator by substituting $k+1$ in the equation: $m=(n^3+k+1)/kn=(n^3+an)/((an-1)n)=(n^2+a)/(an-1)$. Now we can work with $n^2$: $n^2=m(an-1)-a=amn-(a+m)$. Since $a+m\mod n = 0$, we can use this to further decrease the exponent of $n$: because $a+m=bn, b \in \mathbb{N} \implies n+(a+m)/n=n+b=am$.

As $a,m$ increase, $am$ grows much faster than $a+m$, so let's look at lower bound of $am$. $\underset{a>0,m>0,a+m=bn}{\min(am)}=(bn-1)*1=bn-1$. If $n+b=\underset{a>0,m>0,a+m=bn}{\min(am)}=bn-1 \implies n=b(n-1)-1$. Now we can reduce the set of plausible values of $n$ and $b$ purely by observation. For $n>3$ and $b>1$, $n<b(n-1)-1=\underset{a>0,m>0,a+m=bn}{\min(am)}-b \leq am-b \implies n+b<am$. So $n \leq 3$ or $b=1$ (or both).

Let set $S$ be a set of solutions $(m,n)$ and from the above we can simply check case by case:

1. $n=1$: $k=2/(m-1) \implies m=2,k=2$ or $m=3,k=1$. So
   $\{(2,1),(3,1)\} \subset S$.
2. $n=2$: $k=9/(2m-1) \implies m=1,k=9$ or $m=2,k=3$ or $m=5,k=1$. So
   $\{(1,2),(2,2),(5,2)\} \subset S$.
3. $n=3$: $k=28/(3m-1) \implies m=1,k=14$ or $m=5,k=2$. So
   $\{(1,3),(5,3)\} \subset S$.
4. $b=1$: $a+m=n, n>3 \space$ (since we just checked these) $\implies n+1=am$. Taking minimum again, $\underset{a>0,m>0,a+m=n}{\min(am)}=(n-1)*1=n-1<n+1$. If $\underset{a>1,m>1,a+m=n}{\min(am)}=(n-2)*2>n+1$, then $n>=6$, so we have to check only $3 < n < 6$:

   - $n=4$: $16=4am-4 \implies 5=am \implies 1<=m<5$. For $n=4$ and $1<=m<5$, $k \notin \mathbb{N}$.
   - $n=5$: $25=5am-5 \implies 6=am \implies 1<=m<6$. For $n=5$ and $1<=m<6$,
     $k \in \mathbb{N}$ iff $m=2$ or $m=3$. So $\{(2,5),(3,5)\} \subset S$.

Thus set of solutions $S$ is $\{(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,5),(5,2),(1,3),(5,3),(2,5)\}$.